Attach crawlspace vent fan to cinder block
I’m preparing to install a crawlspace vent fan onto a cinder block wall. The manufacturer’s instructions recommend drilling into the cinder block and using wall anchors, which seems straightforward. However, I recently came across comments from retired masons that gave me pause. One said, “I loved it when plumbers and electricians drilled into bricks. The bricks would crack, and I’d get paid to replace them.” Another mason agreed, saying, “I’ve fixed a lot of brick and block work after electricians, plumbers, and ductwork specialists.”
This has led me to question whether drilling into the cinder block is the best practice, especially if I want to avoid cracking it. Are there alternative methods for attaching this fan? Could I use hot glue, liquid nails, or butyl tape to get the job done?


I would not trust adhesives to last.
Drilling/screwing near edges is a problem area for cracks.
If the fan will not fit to the centres of the blocks, screw some wood/plywood with tapcons and screw the fan to the wood.
Tapcons do not use hollow wall anchors that tend to spread out.
